# read parameters from url using POST method in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I read somewhere in this forum that I can create a form using javascript like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="postLogin()">Log me into this website</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function postLogin() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "index2.html");

    var params = {checktype: 'uid', user: 'adam', password: 'pass1234', profile: 'dart', defaultdb: 'kts'};
    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
</script>
```

In this form, it using POST method and will navigate to `index2.html`. And in my `index2.html`, I need these parameters like `checktype`,`user`,`password` to continue process something. How can I read these parameters in `index2.html`. I already tried something like:

```
   <script>
                var query = window.location.search;
                .....
    </script>
```

in my `index2.html` but the return `query`showed nothing. I think it's because that in the POST method, no parameters included in the url so I can not read them using `window.location.search`. Can anyone have an idea how can I read the parameters sending using the POST method?

Comment: Yes you can. Have you tried how far you can get with `window.location.search`?

Comment: I would add by the way, that it is generally NOT a good idea to pass passwords via the querystring.

Comment: Why are you doing a submit do a different page if you are processing with Javascript anyway? Why not just do the processing in the `postLogin()` method?

Comment: Hi Rijk, the form I mentioned above is only an example, my real form is different but the scenarior is the same. What I am going to do is: I am having a list of chart showing on index1.html. and when the user click to the a tag which list next to every chart, the new window appear (index2.html) and then showing only this choosen chart. That why I need these parameters so that in my index2.html, I can use them to draw again this chart.

Comment: I already tried: window.location.search, but when I printed the result out, it showed nothing

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a dynamic web application you should use a server side language (to generate html). Basically yes you can access to query params with javascript.

You can define a function in your index2.html:

```
function getQueryParam ( name , queryString ) {
    var match = RegExp( name + '=([^&]*)' ).exec( queryString || location.search );
    return match && decodeURIComponent( match[ 1 ] );
}
```

and again in your index2.html use this function to access the parameter you want (for example for parameter 'checkType'):

```
getQueryParam('checkType')
```

Of course these should be in 'script' tag.

Comment: Hi Areca, could you please explain a bit more clear about that, sorry because I am new in html and javascript

Comment: now I understand your solution, but I am still confused that I tried to get the queryString by using: window.location.search, but it returned null :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Data from the request body is not made available to client side JavaScript by the browser.

You can read it *only* using server side code.

Comment: Hi Quentin, could you please give me an example how can I read it from the server side?

Comment: @Sonn — First pick a programming language supported by your server (then read an introductory forms tutorial for that language).